# use a value in the variable as key to access json in node js

Tags: node.js, json

JSON data :
{

```
"8500500561":{
         "food":"400",
         "cloth":"44",
         "travel":"44"
         }
```

}

I'll get the key value to access the JSON data dynamically

Node.js file :

```
 const fs  = requrie('fs');
 let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
 let mydata = JSON.parse(rawdata);
 mob = '8500500561';
 console.log(mydata.mob.food);
```

but when I use this I'm getting an error :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'food' of undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file)

Comment: By writing `mydata.mob` you are looking for the key `mob` in the object `mydata`. What you should be doing is `mydata[mob]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MadWard is correct in his comment. You would to structure it like this. You do have some typos in your example you are probably aware of but just pointing them out in case.

```
const fs  = requrie('fs'); //should be require
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
let mydata = JSON.parse(rawdata);
mob = '8500500561'; //850050051 in dataFile
console.log(mydata[mob].food);
```